# Issues running unit tests following upgrade from aiohttp 3.6.2 to 3.7.4

Tags: python-3.6, python-unittest, aiohttp

I'm currently trying to upgrade a python UI from aiohttp 3.6.2 to 3.7.4
My UI is running fine, but some of the unit tests are failing.
I have identified that the unit tests are not picking up flash messages (UI when run picks them up correctly), but cannot see why.
There is also a problem with the unit tests when reading session data, where I have encountered a 403 error.

I know the above is vague, and I can post code samples, but wanted to know if anyone had encountered anything similar, and what they may have done to resolve?

Stepping through the code I have found that the unit test keeps the flash message when using render_template, but looses it when redirecting with HTTPFOUND

Comment: Resolved the issue.
After much digging around, it turns out there is a known bug in aitohttp 3.7.x that effects 'raise' calls. Changing them to 'return' clears the unit test issue without breaking the UI.
Apparently the bug is fixed in aiohttp 3.8.0

Comment: If you've resolved the issue, it might be good to post the solution as an answer to your own question.  This will help future readers and may give you some points and maybe a badge, if people like your answer.